# Code works in HTML, but not JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

The code below is not working in jsp page. What could be the error?

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Geocoding service</title>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
      <script>         
         function codeAddress() {         
             var address = document.getElementById("address").value;                      
             var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
             geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results,status) {
             var location = results[0].geometry.location;
             alert('LAT: ' + location.lat() + ' LANG: ' + location.lng());});
         }
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', codeAddress);     
      </script>   
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="panel">       <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Tembhurkheda, Maharashtra, INDIA">       <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jsp uses java, why tag php?

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser console.It is throwing following error

```
js:35 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
```

You need to get KEY to use this api. And should be used as

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[Refer this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)